# erro de codigo matlab

Tags: matlab

Alguém me pode dar uma ajuda por favor? Estou a tentar fazer um programa em octave e esta me a dar o seguinte erro:

> max recursion depth exceeded
>
> error caled from
>
> size at line 3 column 3
>
> gastos at line 2 column 5

Primeiro implementei uma função gasto para determinar o gasto de uma viatura, com um consumo c (em litros/100km) ao percorrer uma dada distância, dab (dada em km), entre duas cidades com altitudes ha e hb (medidas em metros).

```
function gc = gasto(ha,hb,dab,c)
  if dab == 0
    gc = 0;

  else
    gc = (c/100) * dab * (1+ 100*(hb-ha)/(1000*dab))^2;

  end;
end
```

Depois implementei uma função, gastos, para transformar uma matriz de distâncias, indicada pelo parâmetro Grafo, numa matriz de gastos, C, usando a função gasto, aplicável a distâncias não nulas.

```
function G = gastos(Grafo,Altitudes,consumo)
  n = size(Grafo,1);
  G = zeros(n,n);

  for i = 1 : n
    for j = 1 : n

     if Grafo(i,j) == 0;
       G(i,j) = Inf;

     else
       G(i,j) = gasto(Altitudes(i),Altitudes(j),Grafo(i,j),consumo);

     end;
  end;
end
```

eu utilizei Grafo = [0,102,89,0,136; 102,0,157,172,39; 89,157,0,58,0; 0,172,58,0,95; 136,39,0,95,0] Altitudes = [100, 160, 85, 90, 130] consumo = 6.5 e ao chamar a funcao gastos(Grafo,Altitudes,consumo) deu-me esse erro , mas nao percebi porque?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém consegue dizer-me porque é que está a aparecer este erro?

Answer (score 0):

Isto me parece um erro na entrada da função `size`.

Qual o tamanho da variável `Grafo`?

Se a variável `Grafo` estiver vazia, ela tem dimensão zero. Se você pedir o numero de variáveis na dimensão 1 ela irá ter problemas.

> max recursion depth

é uma [variável do sistema](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.2/Recursion.html) que pode estar sendo chamada, se a `Grafo` estiver vazia, neste caso a dimensão 1 é maior que o limite de dimensões. Mas isto é apenas uma idea.

Infelizmente o manual da função [size](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Object-Sizes.html) não dá mais detalhes.

Rodando com os valores adicionados a sua pergunta, obtive

> ```
> G=[       Inf    7.4329    5.5916       Inf    9.2343
>     5.8729       Inf    9.2533   10.2885    2.1600
>     5.9816   11.2033       Inf    3.8353       Inf
>        Inf   12.1085    3.7053       Inf    6.7059
>     8.4543    2.9400       Inf    5.6659       Inf]
> ```

Que é o que eu esperava (não verifiquei os valores).

Comment: Ok,já fiz isso.

Comment: @aluno20000, não consigo reproduzir seu erro! 
E ainda acho que vc está com problemas de entrada de dados. 
Vc consegue reproduzir o erro com este ou um outro [mcve]?

Comment: Nao percebi a pergunta. Eu ja meti o codigo que utilizei em cima, o que é suposto fazer mais? Utilizaste o octave?

Comment: @aluno20000, sim, Utilizei o Octave. Você consegue reproduzir este erro  com um outro exemplo? Veja [mcve] para ter uma idea. Exemplo, se você não fizer as funcões e escrever o codigo todo de uma vez (simples pois é apenas copias e colar) você tem o erro?

Comment: Se eliminar: function gc = gasto(ha,hb,dab,c) e function G = gastos(Grafo,Altitudes,consumo) aparece-me o erro: invalid use of script c:\users\gastos.m in index expression, o que nao me surpreende pois nao existem funcoes no codigo... Ainda nunca me tinha aparecido este erro

Comment: @aluno20000, Dei uma opcão para ter um [mcve], mas você pode ter outras ideias! :D Debugging é uma parte importante e dificil da programacão. Novas ideas serão bem vindas. Além disso, veja que recomendei escrever todo o codigo novamente, sem o uso de funcões. Apenas apagar as declaracões de funcões deve, a priori, dar problemas sim.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas entao porque é que recomendaste apagar : function gc = gasto(ha,hb,dab,c) e function G = gastos(Grafo,Altitudes,consumo), se sabias que o codigo nao ia funcionar?